# React | Npm package - How can I export 2 components for use as an npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, package

So this might be a silly question, but it keeps bugging me for a while now.

Using React, I have created two components (Buttons.js & Message.js), each with an export. However, now I wish to use both of these components as a npm package. I have tested my components using an example without a problem, I then published my npm package without a sweat. But now that I try to use import and render my components, I stumbled on an error.

**Q: How can I export 2 components for use as an npm package**

This is my approach:

### My package

**Buttons.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./Buttons.css";

export const Button = ({ text }) => <div className="button">{text}</div>
```

**Message.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Message.css";

export const Message = ({ type, message }) => <div className={["messageBox", type].join(" ")}>{message}</div>
```

**index.js**

```
export { default as Buttons } from "./Buttons";
export { default as Message } from "./Message";
```

**Package.json**

```
{
   "name": "ui-elements",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "Just a test",
   "main": "dist/index.js"
...
}
```

### My project

```
import Message from "ui-elements";
import Button from "ui-elements";

export default class App extends Component  {
    render () {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Button text="Log in"  />
                <Message type="error" message="Error, awesome..." />
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

### Error message

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: If you published them to an npm package why are you referencing them as relative paths? Shouldnt it be `npm install ui-elements` and then `import { Message, Buttons } from "ui-elements"`

Comment: I have updated my question. I changed them like you mentioned it to "ui-elements"; but it still gives me the above error.

Comment: You have 2 different exports... thats your problem. Check **0xnoob** answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your index.js:

```
import Buttons from "./Buttons";
import Message from "./Message";

export {
  Buttons,
  Message
}
```

But I think ES6 modules are still experimental in node.js, so it could be that you have to rewrite it to the old `module.exports` version:

```
const Buttons = require("./Buttons"); // and rewrite in Buttons.js
const Message = require("./Message"); // and rewrite in Message.js
module.exports = { 
  Buttons, 
  Message 
};
```

Comment: Problem solved thanks to your answer =) The ES6 way worked fine for me. Thank you!